# How to limit map dictionary

Tags: swift

I'm fetching results from User Defaults dictionary I would like to limit fetching for example last 10 items.

```
if let all = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "MyUser") as? [Dictionary<String,Any>] {
 all.map{userModel.init(dictionary: $0)}
}
```

This will fetch all saved items, How could i just limit fetching for last 10?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: UserDefaults is not the proper place to store app data. And if you are the point where you only wish to load some of your data, a database is the proper solution.

Comment: "to limit fetching for example last 10 items"  Nobody even knows what your data contains.

Comment: @rmaddy Is it bad to store only 10 items of chat messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let all = (UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "MyUser") as? [Dictionary<String,Any>])
    ?.suffix(10)
    ?.map(userModel.init(dictionary:))
```

Comment: Thank you, But i'm getting errors with this code, Could you fix it please?

Comment: Without you saying what the error is? Of course not.